# Postgres how to perform following query

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, subquery

Please bare with me as I do not know how to word my question and therefore am having troubles finding a solution.

I have set up a database with Postgresql.

I have 3 columns in one of my tables: ID, Date/Time, and Print Statement.

I would like to:

1. order my table by Date/Time in DESC order
2. Iterate through the rows
3. Save rows that contain "data" until "START" string encountered in Print Statement column
4. if "START" string is equal to "START:123456" return previously encountered rows and row containing "START" string
5. repeat process for the next 100000 rows

example rows:

```
ID               DT                   PS
1                10/5/22 16:03:50     'data'
2                10/5/22 16:03:49     'Start:123456'
3                10/5/22 16:03:48     'data'
4                10/5/22 16:03:47     'START:333333'
5                10/5/22 16:03:46     'data'
6                10/5/22 16:03:45     'data'
7                10/5/22 16:03:44     'data'
8                10/5/22 16:03:43     'START:123456'
9                10/5/22 16:03:42     'data'
10               10/5/22 16:03:41     'data'
```

query should return:

```
1                10/5/22 16:03:50     'data'
2                10/5/22 16:03:49     'Start:123456'
5                10/5/22 16:03:46     'data'
6                10/5/22 16:03:45     'data'
7                10/5/22 16:03:44     'data'
8                10/5/22 16:03:43     'START:123456'
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us some sample rows from your table, enough for us to see what you mean by "the ones that follow until the next "START" string". And, SQL is a *declarative* language that deals in sets of rows: you say what you want. Python is a *procedural* language: you say how to get what you want.

Comment: I understand that the two languages are not alike and therefore I am having troubles. I am new to Postgres/SQL. I have provided example rows and what the query should return. Thank you for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you what you need:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    DT,
    PS
FROM
    ( -- table with calculated NextStartPS column
    SELECT
        *,
        ( -- subquery that determines next START PS
        SELECT
            PS
        FROM
            TableName X -- alias to avoid namespace confusion
        WHERE
            ID >= TableName.ID
            AND PS LIKE 'START:%'
        ORDER BY
            ID
        LIMIT 1
        ) AS NextStartPS
    FROM
        TableName
    ) TableNameWithNextStartPS
WHERE
    NextStartPS = 'START:123456'
ORDER BY
    ID
;
```

First, add a `NextStartPS` column to your original table using a subquery. Then, query that contrived table, selecting rows only if `NextStartPS = 'START:123456'`.

Research subqueries a bit; they mimic procedural/iterative logic and can be very useful. Be careful though: subqueries are slow for this reason and should only be used when a problem calls for it! :)

Comment: Thank you John! I think I was headed towards that direction, I was just looking at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232282/select-rows-until-condition-met.

Comment: Yep, similar strategy in that post. Happy learnings!

Comment: Question, TableName is the table name in which my columns exist. What is TableName X and TableNameWithNextStartPS?

Comment: If you don't rename TableName (in my case with X) within the subquery, the `ID >= TableName.ID` condition won't know which TableName you're referring to! The TableNameWithNextStartPS is just a name I'm giving to the table created within the FROM clause (the one with the new NextStartPS column). I like being verbose with table names for readability.

Comment: I appreciate that. Bare with me please as I'm trying to piece this together. I created a new column and named it "nextstartps" within the original table. My original table is named "test_table". If I run the above query I get the error: "relation tablename does not exist" and points to the line that contains "TableName X". From my understanding the table "TableName X" doesn't exist at this point and therefore it's throwing an error. The only table that exists is the original, "test_table". Maybe I misunderstood. I am supposed to have 2 tables, original + one with the added nextstartps column?

Comment: So TableName X is my table with the extra column "nextstartps" that also has the 3 columns from the original table, TableName is my original table, and TableNameWithNextStartPS is a table we're creating?

Comment: You're overthinking it. The table exists on the disk; it's called test_table. The query simple references the data located in that table. Everywhere you see TableName in my answer, swap it out with test_table. The name X is simply a renaming of test_table within the localized scope of the subquery: you need a way to differentiate the outer test_table from the inner test_table, because the WHERE clause compares the ID column from both. Research subqueries and derived tables a little more to understand the rest. It's a bit too complex for just one comment, unfortunately!

Comment: Ok, it didn't like the names I gave to my columns for some reason and wouldn't execute until I changed them that's why I was having so much trouble. Anyway, I finally got it to run, but I only got it to return rows  with "START:123456" None of the data rows are present. I am going to do some studying over the weekend.

Comment: When you run the query does it match the example I've provided? I'm trying to confirm that the issue is on my end.

Comment: Yes, I tested this on a SQL Server box and it gave me the correct answer. I then switched from TOP 1 syntax to LIMIT 1 syntax, which is different between SQL Server and PostgreSQL.

Comment: It does take too long for 4 million rows. I tried to add LIMIT, but it didn't help much. TYVM for the help.